# How do middle names and last names work in Mexico culture?

Tags: nombres-propios

I just met someone who lives in Mexico, and he said "I am Rafael Hernandez or Rafael Hernandez Rivera, but not Rafael Rivera."

How do middle / last names work in Mexican culture?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about language, it is about culture. I would be more prone to keep it open if it was more related to language like, how to address to someone given this or that names, but I don't think is the case for this question.

Comment: I'm not mexican but will give it a try with my Venezuelan background: People call themselves by their first name... and on some occasions the last name... but I've seen scenarios where it's the opposite (some schools or the university, for example) The middle name is a tool only used by our parents when they want to signal their children (us) that we better get ready to get a earful (or worse) because they are MAD!!!. So... "Hermenegildo, venga acá!". That's fine. But "Hermenegildo Perencejo, venga acá!". Oops! You better have your last will written down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following your example, the full name is divided as follows:

> Rafael - First name (given name)
>
> Hernández - First surname (inherited from first surname of his father)
>
> Rivera - Second surname (inherited from first surname of his mother)

In case of a middle name, it would go in between the first name and the first surname as:

> Rafael (middle name) Hernández Rivera.